# run jsp project in netBeans 8

Tags: jsp, netbeans

I want to run a jsp project in NetBeans8 . this project build successfully but it dosn't run . I have a a.jsp  and main.html . i write these codes below.  i run them with apache tomcat8. please help me to run it.

main.html :

```
<html>    
    <title>Sample Example</title>

    <body>
        <h1>Example of JSP</h1>
        <b>Mathematics</b>
        <hr>
        <form method = "post" action = "a.jsp">
            <font size = "5" face = "Time New Roman">
                <input type = "radio" name = "a1" value = "add" checked>Addition<br>
                <input type = "radio" name = "a1" value = "mul">Multiplication<br>
                <input type = "radio" name = "a1" value = "div">Multiplication<br>
            </font>

            <br><br>
            Enter first value <input name = "t1" value = ""><br>
            Enter second value <input name = "t2" value = ""><br>
            <input type = "submit" name = "result">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

a.jsp:

```
<%@page language = "java"%>
<%@page import = "java.lang.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1><center>Result for<%=request.getParameter("a1")%></center></h1>

        <%
            int number1 = Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter( "t1" ) );
            int number2 = Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter( "t2" ) );
            int result = 0;
            String operation = request.getParameter( "a1" );

            if(operation.equals( "add" ) )
                result = number1 + number2;

            if( operation.equals( "mul" ) )
                result = number1 * number2;

            if( operation.equals( "div" ) )
                result = number1 / number2;
        %>

        Result is<%=result%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry but , really bad phrased question ... what have you tried and what kind of errors did you have?

Comment: try to go to `localhost:8080/nameofyourproject`

Comment: describe `it dosn't run`?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /OperationExample/

type Status report

message /OperationExample/

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.3

Comment: When i tried to run it , this error occur. it build successful but dosn't work.